# Why am I not getting the date back?

Tags: javascript

I am learning Javascript currently and I am taking a crash course, i typed this out to get the date of birth, but I just get NaN, and not the year.

I'd really like for someone help me know what I'm doing wrong, I know it may be something simple I'm missing.

```
function Person(firstName, lastName, dob) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.dob = new Date(dob);
        this.getBirthYear = function() {
            return this.dob.getFullYear();
        }
    }
    
    //Instantiate object
    const person1 = new Person('John', 'Doe', '6-9-2000');
    
    console.log(person1.getBirthYear());
```

Comment: Date.parse would do the job. however you might need to get a little specific about month. `new Date(Date.parse('June 9 2000'))`

Comment: @DigitalDrifter behavior must be browser specific. Firefox logs `NaN` as posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to pass date like this

```js
function Person(firstName, lastName, dob) {
  this.firstName = firstName;
  this.lastName = lastName;
  this.dob = new Date(...dob);
  this.getBirthYear = function() {
    return this.dob.getFullYear();
  }
}
    
//Instantiate object
const person1 = new Person('John', 'Doe', [2011,10,30]);
    
console.log(person1.getBirthYear());
```

Comment: The console still gives me NaN. I was using Firefox, but I checked Chrome and it gives me the date, i dont know why Firefox doesnt though, any idea?

Comment: I've tested my example in Firefox 67.0 (64-bit) and everything works fine

Comment: @tarkh If you care about the month, then does JavaScript "off-by-one" month numbering come into play? Does your `[2011,10,30]` mean October 30, 2011, or November 30, 2011?

Comment: In JS `Date` months and days of the week starts from 0, so 10 means November. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getMonth